# Scale Bezier curve

Tags: bezier-curves

[image]

I want too pinch this curve by scaling it but when i try that it does nothing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't confuse the scale of the vertex with its radius: Scale will affect the handle size, radius will affect the bevel profile size.

You can change the radius, either in the *N* panel > *Transform > Item > Radius*, or with the <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>S</kbd> shortcut, or right click > *Set Curve Radius*.